# Grammar describing an LL(2) language that is not LL(1), in which no rule can produce epsilon?

Tags: parsing, grammar, context-free-grammar, ll-grammar

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10657843/200783) shows a grammar describing an LL(2) language that is not LL(1):

```
S -> a S A | epsilon
A -> a b S | c
```

In this grammar, one of the possibilities for `S` is that it produces `epsilon`, the empty string. Are there any grammars that similarly describe an LL(2) language that is not LL(1), but in which no rule can produce `epsilon`?

Answer (score 1):

Consider this grammar:

```
S -> a S A | a c 
A -> a b S | c
```

It is not LL(1) since there is a First/First conflict for the nonterminal `S` and the terminal `a`.

It is an LL(2) grammar, since it does not contain any epsilon-rules and First sets for each rule are distinct:

```
First_2(a S A) = {aa}
First_2(ac) = {ac}
First_2(a b S) = {ab}
First_2(c) = {c}
```